# Adding Scores To Snake Game İn JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a snake game in JavaScript with HTML. I want to add scores to game.

Here is what I've tried:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(tailSize, tailSize, tailSize, tailSize - 3);
    var scoreText = function() {
    var score_text = tailSize - 3 ;
    ctx.fillText(score_text,2000,tailSize.length);
    }
    scoreText();
```

All code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Snake</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>
      var canvas, ctx;

      window.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent);

        // her saniye X'i renderla 
        var x = 8;
        setInterval(draw, 1000 / x);
      };

      // oyun boyutu
      var gridSize = (tileSize = 20); // 20 x 20 = 400
      var nextX = (nextY = 0);

      // TISSS YILAAAN 
      var defaultTailSize = 3;
      var tailSize = defaultTailSize;
      var snakeTrail = [];
      var snakeX = (snakeY = 10);

      // Amasya Elması
      var appleX = (appleY = 15);

      // Ekrana Çiz
      function draw() {
        // Yılanı sonraki pos'a (pozisyona) ilerlet
        snakeX += nextX;
        snakeY += nextY;

        // Yılan Oyun Alanının Dışına Çıkarsa
        if (snakeX < 0) {
          snakeX = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeX > gridSize - 1) {
          snakeX = 0;
        }

        if (snakeY < 0) {
          snakeY = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeY > gridSize - 1) {
          snakeY = 0;
        }

        //Yılan Elmayı Yakalarsa
        if (snakeX == appleX && snakeY == appleY) {
          tailSize++;

          appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
          appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
        }

        //Arkaplanı Boya
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Yılanı Boya
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        for (var i = 0; i < snakeTrail.length; i++) {
          ctx.fillRect(
            snakeTrail[i].x * tileSize,
            snakeTrail[i].y * tileSize,
            tileSize,
            tileSize
          );

          //Yılan Kendine Çarparsa
          if (snakeTrail[i].x == snakeX && snakeTrail[i].y == snakeY) {
            tailSize = defaultTailSize;
          }
        }

        // Amasya Elmasını Boya :D
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileSize, appleY * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

        //set snake trail
        snakeTrail.push({ x: snakeX, y: snakeY });
        while (snakeTrail.length > tailSize) {
          snakeTrail.shift();
        }
      }

      // tuşlar
      function keyDownEvent(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 37:
            nextX = -1;
            nextY = 0;
            break;
          case 38:
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = -1;
            break;
          case 39:
            nextX = 1;
            nextY = 0;
            break;
          case 40:
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = 1;
            break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use the `fillText()` method of the canvas object to draw text onto your canvas. You just have to make sure that it is the final drawing operation - so the text doesn't get overwritten by the background for example.

Simply make the call to `fillText()` the last command inside the `draw()` function.

Here's an example where I've used a global variable called **score** to keep track of the collected fruits.

To see it in action click on 'Run code snippet'.

```js
var score = 0;
var gridSize = (tileSize = 20); // 20 x 20 = 400
var nextX = (nextY = 0);

// TISSS YILAAAN 
var defaultTailSize = 3;
var tailSize = defaultTailSize;
var snakeTrail = [];
var snakeX = (snakeY = 10);

// Amasya Elması
var appleX = (appleY = 15);

// Ekrana Çiz
function draw() {
  // Yılanı sonraki pos'a (pozisyona) ilerlet
  snakeX += nextX;
  snakeY += nextY;

  // Yılan Oyun Alanının Dışına Çıkarsa
  if (snakeX < 0) {
    snakeX = gridSize - 1;
  }
  if (snakeX > gridSize - 1) {
    snakeX = 0;
  }

  if (snakeY < 0) {
    snakeY = gridSize - 1;
  }
  if (snakeY > gridSize - 1) {
    snakeY = 0;
  }

  //Yılan Elmayı Yakalarsa
  if (snakeX == appleX && snakeY == appleY) {
    tailSize++;
    score++;
    appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
    appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
  }

  //Arkaplanı Boya
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Yılanı Boya
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  for (var i = 0; i < snakeTrail.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(
      snakeTrail[i].x * tileSize,
      snakeTrail[i].y * tileSize,
      tileSize,
      tileSize
    );

    //Yılan Kendine Çarparsa
    if (snakeTrail[i].x == snakeX && snakeTrail[i].y == snakeY) {
      tailSize = defaultTailSize;
    }
  }

  // Amasya Elmasını Boya :D
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileSize, appleY * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

  //set snake trail
  snakeTrail.push({
    x: snakeX,
    y: snakeY
  });
  while (snakeTrail.length > tailSize) {
    snakeTrail.shift();
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText("score: " + score, 25, 25);
}

// tuşlar
function keyDownEvent(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      nextX = -1;
      nextY = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      nextX = 0;
      nextY = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      nextX = 1;
      nextY = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      nextX = 0;
      nextY = 1;
      break;
  }
}

var canvas, ctx;

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent);

// her saniye X'i renderla 
var x = 8;
setInterval(draw, 1000 / x);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work. you have the `tailSize` at start by 3 and are increasing by 1 on each capture of red. so you can use that to calculate the score

```js
var canvas, ctx, scorediv;

      window.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.scorediv = document.getElementById("score");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent);

        // her saniye X'i renderla 
        var x = 8;
        setInterval(draw, 1000 / x);
      };

      // oyun boyutu
      var gridSize = (tileSize = 20); // 20 x 20 = 400
      var nextX = (nextY = 0);

      // TISSS YILAAAN 
      var defaultTailSize = 3;
      var tailSize = defaultTailSize;
      var snakeTrail = [];
      var snakeX = (snakeY = 10);

      // Amasya Elması
      var appleX = (appleY = 15);

      // Ekrana Çiz
      function draw() {
        // Yılanı sonraki pos'a (pozisyona) ilerlet
        snakeX += nextX;
        snakeY += nextY;

        // Yılan Oyun Alanının Dışına Çıkarsa
        if (snakeX < 0) {
          snakeX = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeX > gridSize - 1) {
          snakeX = 0;
        }

        if (snakeY < 0) {
          snakeY = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeY > gridSize - 1) {
          snakeY = 0;
        }

        //Yılan Elmayı Yakalarsa
        if (snakeX == appleX && snakeY == appleY) {
          tailSize++;

          appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
          appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
        }

        //Arkaplanı Boya
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Yılanı Boya
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        for (var i = 0; i < snakeTrail.length; i++) {
          ctx.fillRect(
            snakeTrail[i].x * tileSize,
            snakeTrail[i].y * tileSize,
            tileSize,
            tileSize
          );

          //Yılan Kendine Çarparsa
          if (snakeTrail[i].x == snakeX && snakeTrail[i].y == snakeY) {
            tailSize = defaultTailSize;
          }
        }

        // Amasya Elmasını Boya :D
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileSize, appleY * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

        //set snake trail
        snakeTrail.push({ x: snakeX, y: snakeY });
        while (snakeTrail.length > tailSize) {
          snakeTrail.shift();
        }

        this.scorediv.innerHTML = "Score : " + (tailSize -3);
      }

      // tuşlar
      function keyDownEvent(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 37:
            nextX = -1;
            nextY = 0;
            break;
          case 38:
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = -1;
            break;
          case 39:
            nextX = 1;
            nextY = 0;
            break;
          case 40:
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = 1;
            break;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Snake</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <div id="score"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help buddy :)) That works well . Now I'm trying to colorize the snake's head . But it dont works too . May i want one more help from you .. :D        
  drwhd = canvas.getContext("2d");                                                                      
   function drawHead() {
     
  drwhd.fillStyle = "white";
  drwhd.fillRect(
  snakeTrail[tileSize].x * tileSize,
  snakeTrail[tileSize].y * tileSize,
  tileSize,
  tileSize
  );
    }                        //              thats code of i add

Comment: share your code that you tried via stackblitz and explain the stuff you are expecting in detail to help you